# Не работают команды show dbs/collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongo

Доброго времени суток.

Использование команд:

1. show dbs - ноль реакции
2. show collections - выдает ошибку **Warning: unable to run listCollections, attempting to approximate collection names by parsing connectionStatus**

Шаги воспроизвидения:

1. mongo
2. use admin
3. show collections

MongoDB shell version v4.4.8 ||  MongoDB server version: 4.4.8

Скриншот прилагается[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрите сообщение на форуме: [Understanding command output](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/understanding-command-output/108395) и соответствующую [документацию `system.users` Collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/system-users-collection/).